# How to handle Gmail address alias between two users

Tags: gmail

I have 2 Google Workspace accounts with Gmail with one alias that delivers messages to both accounts.
I would like to find a smart way to handle messages and connected tasks between users. Currently we have the problem that user1 doesn't know if user2 has already replied to email and so on. The current bad solution is to keep the second user in CCN.

We have the option of a shared mailbox, but it seems we need a new account Google (with a new license) with delegation and I really don't want to have another separate account to check.

Do you have any suggestion?